# Is there any way to determine text direction from CultureInfo in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I have looked around, but I have been unable to figure this out, some languages are read and written from right to left, instead of left to right.  It seems like a no-brainer to be able to get the text direction from the CultureInfo object somehow, but I have not seen it anywhere.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft
```

This will return true if the current culture is read from right to left.

Comment: Thanks John.  I was inspecting the CultureInfo object, but I overlooked this.

Comment: I googled it and found this post. Took me about 10 seconds. So if this question helps 3.5 more people, posting it was most definitely worth it!

Comment: CultureInfo.TextInfo get me an Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo.TextInfo.get'

Comment: Use CurrentCulture to make it work:
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft