# Is there any way to detect an RTL language in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, globalization, right-to-left

I need to be able to detect whether the current language my user is viewing is an RTL (Right To Left) language like Arabic, so I can include a specific CSS file in my pages.

At the moment I'm just detecting this based on the language code of the CultureInfo object, but there must be a better way?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127773

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
CultureInfo.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft
```