# Is there any way for getting the direction of writing in specific culture?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, culture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to determine text direction from CultureInfo in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127773/is-there-any-way-to-determine-text-direction-from-cultureinfo-in-asp-net)

I want to get writing direction of any culture that user select in my application. for example I want to get `rtl` when my user use `fa-IR` culture and get `ltr` when `en-US` is selected.

Is there a built-in solution for this in .NET?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127773/is-there-any-way-to-determine-text-direction-from-cultureinfo-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the TextInfo.IsRightToLeft property to determine this:

```
bool isRightToLeft = new CultureInfo("fa-IR").TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for details.