# Find the flow direction from CurrentCulture in c#

Tags: c#, localization

HI
Is there any way to get the FlowDirection for current culture.

I have set a property like

```
public string FlowDirection
{
get {
return // should return the flow direction using Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.
}
}
```

I dont want to hardcode something like

```
if (currentLanguage.ToLower().StartsWith("ar"))
{
     return FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
}
else
{
    return FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to determine text direction from CultureInfo in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127773/is-there-any-way-to-determine-text-direction-from-cultureinfo-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use this: `CultureInfo.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft`

taken from [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127773/is-there-any-way-to-determine-text-direction-from-cultureinfo-in-asp-net)

Comment: Hi, Forgot to mention, I am using Silverlight 4.0 and there doesn't seem to be a property in CultureInfo.TextInfo as IsRightToLeft