# Changing page direction (Right-to-Left/ Left-To-Left) based on Localization settings in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

How can I change the page direction based on the local setting of the user? from left to right to right-to-left? 
Should this be done using JS only, or there is a better way? please note that I need to Change to value, not check the current culture settings.

Using ASP.NET MVC5

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate. Are you talking about text alignment, or alignment of everything (images etc) ?

Comment: I am talking about whole page direction, that is including text alignment. this can be manually done by using dir="rtl" in the <body> element. but I need to do this dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to determine text direction from CultureInfo in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127773/is-there-any-way-to-determine-text-direction-from-cultureinfo-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set the text direction of the whole page in HTML 5, you can set the `dir` attribute on the `html` or `body` element.  (In HTML 5 the `dir` attribute can be used on any element).

For instance if you're setting the CurrentThread CurrentCulture in the request, you can use the following in your view:

```
<html
 dir="@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft? "rtl" : "ltr")">
```

Based on http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx

Note that if you're using a CSS library such as bootstrap, you'll also need to get an rtl-modified version of the CSS, because the page direction won't affect css rules.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use this rtl-modified css? I am trying to use https://rtlcss.com/cdn/css-frameworks/bootstrap/index.html this one in my website. Both CSS would be included in the solution or whaT?

Comment: I think that's another question!  I would ask it separately.